# Getting Caught exception: Error: write after end after upgrading Node version

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My Node.js application was running fine under Node v10.29.

, when the version of "node" .

After I updated Node to version 12.0, I started getting a `Caught exception: Error: write after end` error:

> Caught exception: Error: write after end at
>   ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (_http_outgoing.js:413:15) at
>   ServerResponse.res.write
>   (/home/node_app_name/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/compress.js:110:17)
>   at ServerResponse.res.end
>   (/home/node_app_name/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/compress.js:116:14)
>   at ServerResponse.res.send
>   (/home/node_app_name/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:152:8) at
>   /home/node_app_name/models/file_name.js:1205:61 at
>   /home/node_app_name/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:414:16 at
>   /home/node_app_name/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection.js:497:9 at Server.Base._callHandler
>   (/home/node_app_name/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:382:41)
>   at
>   /home/node_app_name/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:472:18
>   at MongoReply.parseBody
>   (/home/node_app_name/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)
>
> Caught exception: Error: write after end at
>   ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (_http_outgoing.js:413:15) at
>   ServerResponse.res.write
>   (/home/node_app_name/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/compress.js:110:17)
>   at ServerResponse.res.end
>   (/home/node_app_name/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/compress.js:116:14)
>   at ServerResponse.res.send
>   (/home/node_app_name/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:154:8) at fn
>   (/home/node_app_name/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:794:10) at
>   View.exports.renderFile [as engine]
>   (/home/node_app_name/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:222:12) at
>   View.render
>   (/home/node_app_name/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:76:8) at
>   Function.app.render
>   (/home/node_app_name/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:504:10)
>   at ServerResponse.res.render
>   (/home/node_app_name/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:798:7) at
>   Request._callback
>   (/home/node_app_name/app/controllers/file_name.js:92:16)

I searched a lot for the above error, but I am still not able to get a working solution for it.

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using res.send(...); more than once in the code (within a block of route code app.get('path', function(req, res){ });). Than change it as res.write(....);

Comment: ThnQ Rahaman, for your reply, but am not using res.send more than once in the same route code block, I use it only once,

Besides this,

as node is asynchronous, once the res is send is res.send(), I even end the response with res.end() and return from that block of code by writing "return;" as well

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put  response.end();  in every end of the statement path ("/" or "/etc").